# symfony transaction commits only one time

Tags: php, symfony, transactions, doctrine, entitymanager

While using symfony 2.5 with doctrine, I'm trying to start a new transaction for each user, do some work with that user, persist some entities and flush and commit everything at once.

For the first user it's working, All my entities are committed to the database, but the second and so on aren't committed anymore. The commands are executed, but nothing happens in the database.

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $this->em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    //Do some stuff
    $this->em->persist($user);
    //Do some more stuff
    $this->em->persist($organisation);
    //Do even more stuff
    $this->em->persist($account);

    try {
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->em->getConnection()->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->em->getConnection()->rollback();
        $this->em->close();
        throw $e;
    }       
}


/**
 * ICM\IPTVManagerBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ICM\IPTVManagerBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User 
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\Column(type = "integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $username
     * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 45, unique = true)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Organisation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "organisation_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
     * @Assert\NotNull(groups = {"viewer"})
     */
    protected $organisation;
```

both the user and the organisation are existing entities, only the account is not an existing entitie and need to be created, user and organisation need to be updated.

But... account is not related to user and organisation. That relation is made by hand because multiple entities can have an account and i'm not willing to create an accounttable for each entity.

I need to be able to roll all the database changes back as soon as there is a problem somewhere, but i don't want all the users to be handled and roll back all users if there is a problem with only one of the users.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Bare in mind that `persist` does not actually send anything to the database, but is only used to add new entities to the manager.  Doctrine creates a transaction internally when you call `flush`.

Comment: This hard to answer without knowing the relation between user, organisation and account. Can you please post the relevant parts of your entities?

Comment: i know that flush creates the transaction. Everytime i need to send my user to the database flush is called first before i commit the transaction

Comment: What do you mean, "the commands are executed"?  You know the PHP gets run, or you see SQL statements hitting the DB, or what?

Comment: Can you look at Symfony toolbar? Search there for executed sql queries, what do you see?

Comment: @frumious: I can see the php code being executed. Don't know if the sql statements hit the DB. Guess not, because nothing is inserted or updated in the db

Comment: Well, I'm stuck.  Symfony toolbar might conceivably help, but if it just says that the SQL's running and it's clearly not, that's not much help!  If it were me I'd debug one of the non-functional loop iterations to follow execution through the Doctrine code, to see if it's doing something weird with the transactions, but you may not have that facility available.